# Convert ISO Date string to date in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Need help to convert exactly from ISO Date string to Date:
I have an ISO string date: "2016-01-23T22:23:32.927".
But when I use `new Date(dateString)` to convert Date, the result is wrong:

```
var date = new Date("2016-01-23T22:23:32.927");
```

The result is: `Sun Jan 24 2016 05:23:32 GMT+0700`. It's not true. I want the date is 23 not 24.

Please help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you're willing and able to add a dependency, I recommend using moment.js for this. It makes date handling in Javascript much more straightforward and a lot safer, and fixes your specific problem right out of the box.

To do this, 1st load it from a CDN, e.g. [Moment.JS 2.14.1 minified](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js). Then use it as follows:

```
var date = moment("2016-01-23T22:23:32.927");
console.log(date);
// output:  Sat Jan 23 2016 22:23:32 GMT-0500
```

...i.e. your desired result :)

[Here's a jsfiddle demonstrating this.](https://jsfiddle.net/andfaulkner/brauytju/)

Comment: I'm not sure where the downvote is coming from - this answer gives the required result in multiple JS environments (tested in Node 4, Chrome, IE10, FF), and further, it solved the OP's issue. If it's the suggested dependency, I still stand by my answer - it avoids the main traps such answers tend to fall into: 1) I'm not making assumptions about the OP's project: Moment can be effortlessly dropped into virtually anything; 2) I'm not advising the addition of a large framework or general-purpose library (e.g. React or jQuery) - it's a small, focused library aimed at problems similar to the OP's.

Comment: Also, the dependency isn't an "overkill" suggestion - it's actually good advice in general, regardless of whether the OP is having this problem or not. The JS Date object is broken in numerous ways, has a lot of counterintuitive behaviour, and in some cases even introduces security holes. It should not be used in production webapps in its naked form. The OP should be using MomentJS for dates anyway...doing so just happens to also automatically solve their specific issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific issue with the answer.

Comment: You happen to get the same day of the month back because your environment's timezone is GMT-0500. It would still return a different day of the month in the OP's environment as his is set to GMT+0700. There is no reason to use moment in your example. Please see my answer for an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply a timezone offset with your iso date. Since there isn't one, it assumes the date to be in GMT and when you log it out, it prints it in the timezone of your browser. I think that if you pass `"2016-01-23T22:23:32.927+07:00"` to `new Date()` you would get the value you are expecting.

Comment: Thank you, @rdubya. But that string Date which I get from DB

Comment: @DoanMinhTien I'm just pointing out that the date that it is creating is the correct date for the string you are providing it. If you need to do manipulations on it, you will need to assume that it is in GMT time unless you convert it to another timezone. Vijay's suggestion to use moment.js can help with that, but it needs the timezone information as well.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript environments (browser, node,...) use a single timezone for formatting dates as strings. Usually this is your system's timezone. Based on the output you get, yours is GMT+0700.

So what happened:

- The string you passed as ISO format to the `Date` constructor doesn't specify a timezone. In this case it is treated as UTC.
- When you then output the date (I'll assume with `console.log`), it is converted to the timezone of your environment. In this case 7 hours where added.

If that doesn't suit you, you can change the way you output the date. This depends on what output you want, e.g.:

- If you just want the UTC timezone again, you can use `date.toISOString()`.
- If you want to output it in another timezone, you can call `date.getTimezoneOffset()` and figure out the difference between both timezones. You'd then probably need to get the individual date parts and add/subtract the timezone difference accordingly. At this point you could consider using an existing library, taking into account their possible disadvantages.

Answer (score -1):

Use `date.toUTCString()` 
it'll give you 23 instead of 24 as it Convert a date object to a string, **according to universal time**